# I keep getting a CANNOT GET/ error in my reactjs app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-hooks, body-parser

Im creating a reactJS app for an AI hackathon but i keep getting this error:
This is my App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [response, setResponse] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch("http://localhost:3001", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ message }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setResponse(data));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <textarea
          value={message}
          onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
        ></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <div>{response.message}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my index.js

```
//Server end which handles API requests
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const port = 3001;
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    res.json({message: 'Hello World'});
});

app.listen(port,() => {
    console.log('listening at http://localhost:'+port);
});
```

I was expecting the code to run properly because i genuinely can't figure out where i went wrong.

Here is the debug console and error
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqayf.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSmRM.png

Comment: Just a tip, you do NOT need to install and import body-parser manually if you're using Express 4.16+. Body-parser is included in the express package from this version. You can use app.use(express.json()); to parse JSON bodies and app.use(express.urlencoded()); to parse URL-encoded bodies

Answer (score 0):

Could you attach exactly the error you get. Question says that you get an error "CANNOT GET/" but I see you are sending a request with POST. The code itself seems to be fine for a post method.

Comment: I've attached the screenshots of the debug console and the error